# SQL Select within 24 hours?

Tags: sql

People.Born is of type datetime. I would like to delete only the people that were born within the last 24 hours. I am running this as a stored procedure inside of Visual Studio 2010.

Here is my attempt:

```
DELETE 
FROM People
WHERE People.Born >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE());
```

Please help is possible

Comment: which db system are you using? Date functions can differ.

Comment: What happened when you ran that query?

Comment: I am not seeing a problem with the SQL you wrote.  We are going to need some more info, such as what DBMS you are using and if you are receiving any errors with that sql

Comment: What about people who were born yesterday? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not positive which version of SQL you're using, but I've never seen "day" as an appropriate first argument to dateadd.  Try dd instead:

```
DELETE 
FROM People
WHERE People.Born >= DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE());
```

Comment: `day` is an appropriate argument. `dd` is [just an abbreviation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) for `day`.

Comment: Learn something new every day! Thanks for the tip.