# SQL get within 24 hours

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Select within 24 hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935864/sql-select-within-24-hours)

I am using regular SQL to attempt to run a query. Here is what my table looks like:

```
Products
-----------------
Product ID  
Date 
Weight
```

---

The Date is enter as a datetime into the database.

I want to be able to select only the items whos Product.Date is within the past 24 hours. I have been trying to get this for sometime now and here is what I have gotten:

```
Select Products.Date
FROM Products
WHERE Products.Date < DATEADD(d,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

This isn't working for some reason and I get the following product dates:

```
2011-01-18 00:00:00.000
2010-01-20 14:23:00.000
2011-01-20 04:05:00.000
```

Comment: Helps if we know what database (including version) you're working on.

Comment: Is this just a repost of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935864/sql-select-within-24-hours)?

Comment: Please don't repost questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment on the other post, if you only want the previous 24 hours (so excluding future dates) then try this:

```
SELECT Products.Date
FROM   Products
WHERE  Products.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(d,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: thanks! that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Not a problem. Remember to click the tick next to the right of the answer when you have found a solution :)

Answer (score 5):

Could it be that you actually wanted `>` instead of `<`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Products.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(d,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` thus ignoring future dates?

Comment: Tried using the > but it actually doesn't return anything. This one I actually do want:

2011-01-20 04:05:00.000

Comment: @StuartBlackler, if there is something in the future, then yes.

Comment: @user965824, `>=` then? Is it datetime or date type?

Comment: @user965824 - And how do you know that's not correct? Maybe there are no products in your database with a Date within the past 24 hours.

Comment: The date you're trying to get is from January of 2011, which is a year ago

Comment: Indeed, that sounds like a bit more than 24 hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

The dates are 2011, and the current year is 2012 :)

You also want to use >

```
Select *
FROM Products
WHERE Products.Date > DATEADD(d,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select [Product ID]
FROM Products
WHERE [Date] > DATEADD(d,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Products.Date
FROM Products
WHERE Products.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(d,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```